# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no product found

Tags: java, spring

Hi while learning spring I got stuck in following code not sure what is wrong with this code

**@Repositiry**

```
 @Repository
    public class ProductRepositiryImpl implements ProductRepositiry {

        private List<Product> listOfAllProducts = null;

        public ProductRepositiryImpl() {
            listOfAllProducts = new LinkedList<>();

            Product iphone = new Product("A1232", "iPhone", new BigDecimal(500));
            iphone.setDescription("iPhone 6s with 5.2' FHD Screen");
            iphone.setManfactuer("Apple");
            iphone.setCategory("Smart Phone");
            iphone.setUnitsInStock(699);

            listOfAllProducts.add(iphone);
        }

        @Override
        public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
            return listOfAllProducts;
        }

        @Override
        public Product getProductsById(String productId) {
            Product productById = null;
            for (Product product : listOfAllProducts) {
                if (product != null && product.getProductId() != null && product.getProductId().equals(productId)) {
                    productById = product;
                    break;
                }

                if (productById == null)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("no product found " + productId);

            }
            return productById;

        }

    }


**Service**



@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    @Autowired
ProductRepositiry productRepositiry;

@Override
public void processOrder(String productId, long count) {
    System.out.println("inside Process Order");

    Product getProductByid = productRepositiry.getProductsById(productId);
    System.out.println("get product by id");
    System.out.println(getProductByid);
    if (getProductByid.getUintsInOrder() < getProductByid.getUnitsInStock()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("OUT OF STOCK" + getProductByid.getUintsInOrder());
    } 
        getProductByid.setUintsInOrder(getProductByid.getUintsInOrder() - count);
}
**@controller**



@Controller
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    OrderService orderService;

    @RequestMapping("/order/A1234/2")
    public String processOrder() {
        System.out.println("process order");
        orderService.processOrder("A1232", 2);
        return "redirect:/product";
    }
}
```

**StackTrack**

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context
>   with path [/web_Store] threw exception [Request processing failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no product
>   found A1233] with root cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no
>   product found A1233   at
>   com.webstore.repoImpl.ProductRepositiryImpl.getProductsById(ProductRepositiryImpl.java:58)
>     at
>   com.webstore.serviceImpl.OrderServiceImpl.processOrder(OrderServiceImpl.java:20)
>     at
>   com.webstore.controller.OrderController.processOrder(OrderController.java:18)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

In class `ProductRepositiryImpl` whenever I am trying to execute method `getProductsById(String productId)` and while debugging I get `productById = product;` holding a valid value then it is supposed to exit loop why it is still getting `IllegalArgumentException` 
any help will be appericiated

Best Regards

Comment: In your example it should not matter, but your `if (productById == null)` is on the wrong place. It should be OUTSIDE the for loop, otherwise it will throw an error if the FIRST product isn't the correct one.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz thanks , I should have looked here first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ProductRepositiryImpl() {
            listOfAllProducts = new LinkedList<>();

            Product iphone = new Product("A1232", "iPhone", new BigDecimal(500));
            iphone.setDescription("iPhone 6s with 5.2' FHD Screen");
            iphone.setManfactuer("Apple");
            iphone.setCategory("Smart Phone");
            iphone.setUnitsInStock(699);

            listOfAllProducts.add(iphone);
    }
```

You are adding the product with **ID A1232**

```
@RequestMapping("/order/A1234/2")
    public String processOrder() {
        System.out.println("process order");
        orderService.processOrder("A1233", 2);
        return "redirect:/product";
    }
```

You are trying to get the Product with **ID A1233**

**EDIT 1:**

As [@Florian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4682610/florian-schaetz) said on comment above. Move check for `productById == null` outside of for loop

```
public Product getProductsById(String productId) {
            Product productById = null;
            for (Product product : listOfAllProducts) {
                if (product != null && product.getProductId() != null && product.getProductId().equals(productId)) {
                    productById = product;
                    break;
                }              
            }
            if (productById == null)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("no product found " + productId);

           return productById;

}
```

Comment: actually this is not the reason, look at the comment by @FlorianSchaetz , solved the error btw thanks :)

Comment: But well seen. Ironically, the mapping is for A1234 ;-)